How to connect to Google Cloud SQL from Google App Script
I am getting this error in my Google App Script.
9:56:28 AM  Error   
Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.
connectToGoogleCloudSQL @ Code.gs:129

I cannot connect to the Google Cloud SQL.
I just can't figure out what is wrong. The error description is too general. The Connection name was taken from Google Cloud console - Overview and copied from Connection name The database name was taken from Databases menu item, under the name column.
function connectToGoogleCloudSQL() {
      const connectionName = 'projectID:regionId:dbinstanceId'
      const dbName = 'databaseName'
      const username = 'myUserName'
      const password = 'myPassword'
      Line 129 -> const conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://${connectionName}/${dbName}", username, password);

      var stmt = conn.createStatement();
      var sql = 'select 1 from tableID';

      stmt.setMaxRows(100);

      var results = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
      var mapping = {}; 
........


Based on the docs have you given your script the proper access scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice)?
